# How does bad importing works in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I have 3 Vue files, each with a script section. When I am importing the chance js library correctly, all the 3 scripts print a defined object for `console.log(chance)`.

But when I do a bad import,

> import {chance} from 'chance'; //<=this is not correct, but works for other files

instead of

> import {Chance} from 'chance'; //<=this is the correct one

the first script prints undefined, and after, the second and the third script prints the same object printed previously.
Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: It depends on how the specific lib implemented and the way the app is bundled, not Vue or JS. Refer to the docs of the lib. "this is the correct one" - no, it doesn't, unless the lib is specifically published as ES module. If it's CommonJS/UMD module then default import should be used for module interop, `import chance from 'chance'`. But again, this depends on your setup, which is unknown. The question doesn't make sense in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading some documentation with [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) may provide some answers.
For the rest, take the time to learn how JS works in [this section](https://javascript.info/modules).

---

In the end, there is no general answer to that question. It depends on how the library is written.